# How to create exponential restart strategy for specific error types in an Akka stream?

Tags: scala, stream, akka

We have a stream connected to Kafka that needs to have different behavior based on the exception type.  For example, if it has a `SQLException` it should use `Supervision.Stop`, but if it's a `RetriableException` it should use `Supervision.Restart`.

I would also like to be able to implement an exponential backoff strategy for those error types that need to be restarted, but in some testing I did it seems like using the `RestartSource` with a `Decider` causes the `Decider` to be ignored.

What is the best way to implement an exponential backoff strategy for streams that throw a specific error type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the first problem, you can just use the decider pattern:

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case _: ArithmeticException => Supervision.Resume
  case _ => Supervision.Stop
}

implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer(
  ActorMaterializerSettings(system).withSupervisionStrategy(decider))
```

I don't think the `RestartSource` ignores the decider... The decider is a property of the materializer, which is required for the source to start. If it does, you should report a bug to Akka Streams.